# How can I run mysql_upgrade as a part of a docker compose file?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I have a `docker-compose.yml` with a MariaDB database service that looks like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    container_name: misp_db
    image: mariadb
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ${DATA_DIR}/db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
```

When spinning up my containers, I noticed these errors:

```
[ERROR] Missing system table mysql.roles_mapping; please run mysql_upgrade to create it
[ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.event: expected column 'sql_mode' at position 14 to have type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','TRADITIONAL','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION','PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH','EMPTY_STRING_IS_NULL','SIMULTANEOUS_ASSIGNMENT'), found type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','NOT_USED','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_B
[ERROR] mysqld: Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
```

I was able to work around this problem by running `docker exec -it db /bin/bash` to get a shell, and then running `mysql_upgrade -p` and entering my configured MySQL root password, but this should be automated.

How can I do this in Docker Compose?

Comment: Do you not want to pin your mysql version? Right now you are always fetching the latest version, which leads to errors if there are changes indeed. You could write a bash script that checks for an upgrade as a command in your docker-compose file, but I think pinning the version is a more sensible solution. If some application relies on a certain version of mariadb, it could break all of the sudden due to version update.

Comment: One string, not an array:  `SET sql_mode = 'REAL_AS_FLOAT,PIPES_AS_CONCAT,AN...'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run it directly from the docker-compose but it can be done rather simply using a one-line Dockerfile called from docker-compose.

This can be done by simply adding the following to your service definition in the `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
build: .
```

This will cause `docker-compose` to run the Dockerfile located in the working directory ".".

In the Dockerfile, you can then run the upgrade script itself.

```
RUN mysql_upgrade -p
```

This will cause the upgrade to be run once; while building the image. Subsequently, your mySQL version will be frozen at the time you build the image; not when you start the container. This seems like a reasonable approach to me.

You *could* run an entrypoint.sh script from the Dockerfile (see [here](https://success.docker.com/article/use-a-script-to-initialize-stateful-container-data) for more details), which gets called when you start the container. That would perform the upgrade when you start the container as you originally requested but, I agree with @blokje5, upgrading when starting the container seems a bit risky. If they accidentally break something (it happens), then an image that once worked would no longer be working and that can be a bit of a nightmare to debug; especially since it's happening before the service is considered ready.